# error inject() must be called from an injection context when adding a tag to the app.component.html . help me to solve this error

Tags: angular, typescript

strong text:
app.component.html file:

```
    enter code here
```

< h1 >{ { title } }< /h1 >

< app-customers >< /app-customers >

``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
strong text:
Customers.component.ts file:
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
    enter code here
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {CustomerService} from '../customer.service';
import {Customer} from '../Customer';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-customers',
  templateUrl: './customers.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customers.component.css'],
  providers:[CustomerService]
})
export class CustomersComponent implements OnInit {
    Customers: Customer[];
    Customer: Customer;
    Customer_firstname:string;
    Customer_lastname:string;
    phone:string;

  constructor(private CustomerService: CustomerService) {this.CustomerService= CustomerService; }

  ngOnInit(): void {
        this.CustomerService.getCustomers()
            .subscribe( Customers =>
            this.Customers = Customers);
  }

}
``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
strong text 
Customer.service.ts file:
```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
    enter code here
````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http,Headers} from '@angular/http';
import {Customer} from './Customer';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CustomerService {

  constructor(private http:Http) { }


  getCustomers()
  {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/Customers')
    .map(res=>res.json());

  }

  addCustomer(newCustomer)
  {
    var headers= new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type','applicatoin/json');
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/Customer', newCustomer,{headers:headers})
    .map(res=>res.json());
  }


  deleteCustomer(id)
  {
    return this.http.delete('http://localhost:3000/api/Customer'+id)
    .map(res=>res.json());
  }
}
``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
strong text
app.component.ts file:

```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
    enter code here
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'OnlineBank app Works!';
}
``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

strong text:
i am getting error of this type when i am adding the tag  to the app.component.html file:

``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
    enter code here
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
ERROR Error: inject() must be called from an injection context
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.js:925)
    at Module.ɵɵinject (core.js:941)
    at Object.XHRBackend_Factory [as factory] (http.js:1445)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.js:16944)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:16696)
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.js:931)
    at ɵɵinject (core.js:941)
    at injectArgs (core.js:1058)
    at Object.factory (core.js:17114)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.js:16944)
main.ts:12 Error: inject() must be called from an injection context
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.js:925)
    at Module.ɵɵinject (core.js:941)
    at Object.XHRBackend_Factory [as factory] (http.js:1445)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.js:16944)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:16696)
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.js:931)
    at ɵɵinject (core.js:941)
    at injectArgs (core.js:1058)
    at Object.factory (core.js:17114)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.js:16944)
``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: i am getting error when i am adding <app-customers></app-customers>
this tag to app.component.html and if i am remove that tag i am not getting any output

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly is the error you are getting when you add <app-customers> ?

Comment: i am getting this error when i inspect the browser for output:

Comment: core.js:6189 ERROR Error: inject() must be called from an injection context
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.js:925)
    at Module.ɵɵinject (core.js:941)
    at Object.XHRBackend_Factory [as factory] (http.js:1445)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.js:16944)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:16696)
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.js:931)
    at ɵɵinject (core.js:941)
    at injectArgs (core.js:1058)
    at Object.factory (core.js:17114)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.js:16944)

Comment: If you can provide a stackblitz it would be better, one question in your app-customers  any specific reason you have written  `this.CustomerService= CustomerService;`  inside constructor parathesis ?

Comment: here specifying the variable and assigning it to the service and by it would call the service .i think it is not neccessary to that statement

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is due to :

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
```

I suggest to remove the `providedIn` key and declare the service in the `providers` section of your `module`

Comment: i have declared the service in the providers section but still  getting error.and tq for commenting

Comment: what i have to provide in the injectable decorator